# Angular Analyze the project

Tags: angular

I have a project in angular, how can I analyze the project since I am a junior?
1) Are there any tools that can help me understand how it's done?
2) Are there any tools that create a project outline for me?

I know angular quite well.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about what you want to analyze, but try this tool:

https://compodoc.app/guides/installation.html

compodoc shows you your project like a documentation, all your modules , components, services...

Comment: I would like to understand by analyzing the code how it works step by step, is there anything that can help me?

Comment: if you want to debug it, you can use the google chrome console, by going to source and then press ctrl + p or cmd + p and then type the component or service name.